# nginx c module hello world doesn't work

Tags: c, nginx, module

I just download [nginx](http://nginx.org/download/). Then I go to the directory of nginx and do the three commands one by one as below:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

Then I can visit `http://localhost`, everything goes fine.

Now I'm trying to add a c module. Here is a [hello world example](https://github.com/perusio/nginx-hello-world-module).

What I've done is to download the example from Github and edit the config file of nginx (`/pathOfNginx/conf/nginx.conf`) as below:

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
        ############ this is what I add
        location /test {
            hello_world;
        }
        ############ done
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```

After that, I do `./configure --add-module=/path/to/nginx-hello-world-module` and `make`. Everything looks like good.
Then I reload the server: `nginx -s reload`

However, I can't get the right reply. Meaning that when I do `curl -i http://localhost/test`, what I get is an 404 Not Found, instead of a hello world string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me!

Gives a file that contains `hello world\0`...

Remember that the second time you run `./configure` you need to give all of the options again (it's replacing the config, not updating it).

Also you'll need to follow this with a `make install`, otherwise the installed binary won't be updated.

```sh
# get everything
wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.12.0.tar.gz
tar -xvf nginx-1.12.0.tar.gz
git clone https://github.com/perusio/nginx-hello-world-module

# configure
(
  cd nginx-1.12.0
  ./configure --prefix=../nginx --add-module=../nginx-hello-world-module/
)

# build & install
make -C ./nginx-1.12.0 -j8
make -C ./nginx-1.12.0 install

# update config
cat <<EOF >./nginx/conf/nginx.conf
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
        ############ this is what I add
        location /test {
            hello_world;
        }
        ############ done
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
EOF

# run
(
    cd nginx
    ./sbin/nginx
)

# test
curl http://localhost:80/test
```

Comment: I think I've found the reason: `/usr/local/nginx/conf` can't be updated when I reedit `pathOfNginx/nginx/conf/nginx.conf`. I'm not sure what I should do for this issue. For now, what I could do is to `rm -rf /usr/local/nginx` and reconfigure and remake the whole nginx.